# Memory leak using class member

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, memory-leaks

I use a class member called "soapResults" when connecting to a webservice. I use a parser to parse the xml results (it is a json result inside the web service).

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser
         didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName
         namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI
         qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
         attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {
NSString *attName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@Result",methodName];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:attName]) {        
    if (!soapResults) {         
        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
    }       
    elementFound = YES;     
}

[attName release];
}
```

Now soapResults is a retain member and released in dealloc. I tried to release this in the connection fail/pass but did not succeed. I also tried not to alloc it at all but then I get empty results.... Any help would be appriciated

Edit: 
I also get memory leaks inside the parser:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {    
    if (elementFound) {
        [soapResults appendString: string];//Memory leak here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If soapResults is a retain property you should change

```
soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

To

```
self.soapResults = [NSMutableString string];
```

This releases the old value and retains the new one, avoiding leaks.

Comment: I changed my code to `self.soapResults = [NSMutableString string];` and the memory leak is still here...

Comment: If you change soapResults anywhere else in the code, you should also use the self.soapResults accessor. Also if you want to remember the string when the element ends you should make a new string with the mutable string (NSString* s = [NSString stringWithString:soapResults]), so as to copy the data before emptying the NSMutableString for the next element.

Answer (score 0):

You alloc `soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` here but i don't see any release.